# Can't get the return value of the php variable in json which contain javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, json, request, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to create a dynamic javascript code inside my php controller and want to return it to UI which is angular js as JSON, but what I get is `''` in response.

This is my php code which I want to return as json:

```
 $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
 $bcamp = Bcamp::where('user_id','=',intval($user_id))->first();//TODO How to clarify which campaign should be showed.
 $bcamp_id = $bcamp->_id;
 $width = $this->request->input('width');
 $height = $this->request->input('height');

 $script  = "<script type='text/javascript'>";
 $script .= "!( function( w, d ) {";
 $script .= "'use strict';";
 $script .= "var ad = { user: '".$user_id."', campaign_id: '".$bcamp_id."', seat_id: '".$seat_id."', width: '".$width."', height: '".$height."', id: 'iranad-' + ~~( Math.random() * 999999  ) },";
 $script .= "h = d.head || d.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[ 0 ],";
 $script .= "s = location.protocol + '//localhost/banneri/iranad/ia.js';";
 $script .= "if ( typeof w.anetworkParams != 'object' )";
 $script .= "w.anetworkParams = {};";
 $script .= "d.write( '<div id=\"' + ad.id + '\" style=\"display: inline-block\"></div>' );";
 $script .= "w.anetworkParams[ ad.id ] = ad;";
 $script .= "d.write( '<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=' + s + ' async></script>' );";
 $script .= "})( this, document );";
 $script .= "</script>";
 $response = \Response::json($script, $statusCode);
 return $response;
```

I think it's escaping the script. How to solve this?

FYI : It's `Laravel 5.3` framework which I'm working in.

Comment: If you are using AJAX you want to 'echo' instead of 'return'

Comment: If you are not using Ajax than  set required parameters on controller and create javascript code on your view file. json work on  array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$script` is not json. It is a string.

`\Response::json` should be smart enough to handle it and send the response as is, but if you expect json on the client side it will fail to parse it.

I don't see why you need the whole JS code to be returned by your controller. It is pretty much static. The only dynamic part is

```
{ user: '".$user_id."', campaign_id: '".$bcamp_id."', seat_id: '".$seat_id."', width: '".$width."', height: '".$height."', id: 'iranad-' }", which is valid JSON, unless you mess up with values of the variables, e.g. if it has unescaped quotes.
```

Basically what you need to return is:

```
return \Response::json(['user' => $user_id, 'campaign_id' => $bcamp_id ... etc ], $statusCode);
```

for `Response` to convert it to valid json. The response should be loaded into `var ad` on clientside, and add concatenate `ad.id` with `Math.random() * 999999`.